# fail bb-ant-tools build when jdp referenced file is missing

Tags: blackberry, ant

When I build my BlackBerry application with ant, I don't get any error messages, even though three files defined in the jdp file don't exist.

How can I configure the build to fail if source files defined in a jdp file don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

It is not build configuration issue. BB Ant Tools won't raise an error, if one or more of jdp properties point to a wrong resource location.

If you want check the presence of a particular resource and raise error if it is not available, use another ant task that works with files or implement your own ant-task that just does what you want.